# Is it possible to make java script recognize the lowest domain in an iframe as the origin vs highest

Tags: javascript, cors

I'm trying to create a script that spans across multiple sites, and has a central server that manages the third party tracking pixel for all of them.  The issue I'm having is that I want third party tracking pixels to track to the the original domain that generated the lead, vs tracking to the top tier domain when I fire them in an iframe.

Was thinking this could be achieved by using something like shadow doms to control the scope of what the tracking pixels can see, but in all of my attempts so far, the domain that's tracked is the top tier iframe chain.

I know it's annoying to ask a Q w\o a code example, but not really sure how to give an example for what I'm asking.  Only two ways I've been able to think of is preemptively updating the origin vars (which I haven't managed to do successfully and seems jerry-rigged), or somehow loading the third party pixels in a scope controled container (which is what I'd prefer, but also haven't managed to pull off).  Even a point in the right direction would be helpful at this point, as I can't find anything that accomplishes what I'm trying to do as a kick off reference

Clarity Edit:

Top tier site gets a sale that was fed from bottom tier site top tier site iframes a container which contains all third party pixels associated w\ that campaign (facebook google etc)

```
topdomain.com: 

<iframe src="site.com/thank-you.php">
```

site.com/thank-you.php would be:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version="2.0";n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,"script","https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js");
fbq("init", "111"); // Insert your pixel ID here.
fbq("track", "PageView");
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=111&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

or whatever campaign initiated it (it's actually intened to smart load pixels based on traffic source to prevent data co-mingling)  Issue is that the facebook pixel thinks it's firing from the highest level iframe, vs the origin domain I'm trying to link it to.  Basically trying to write something that prevents data tracking pixels from loading on irrelevant campaigns so they're not passively data mining, and also controls the scope on information they can access when loaded.

In that example the FB pixel tracks to topdomain.com instead of site.com.  Long story short I'm trying to write something that limits 3rd party tracking pixels scope so that the site owner can control what they want vs trusting 3rd parties to not passively mine any, and everything.

Comment: Not _really_ sure what your issue actually is. If you don’t have any code, can you then please at least give an illustrative example of what you want to track in which situation (examples of who embeds what, inside of an iframe or outside), and what currently goes wrong with it? Does the tracking pixel allow you to specify parameters with the tracking code, or does it gather all the info it track from its surroundings on its own?

Comment: You could pass custom parameters with the event, that you can evaluate later. Or append something to the iframe src URL itself, that allows you to determine the “referring” domain later on, when using custom conversions.

Comment: I noted that below, I know I can use query params \ custom events to separate the sources for tracking, but this is more about controlling the 3rd party pixels access to information than simple event tracking.  I'm trying to contain what tracking pixels can see so people can limit their permissions internally vs relying on external permissions

Comment: _“but this is more about controling the 3rd party pixels access to information”_ - well that is pretty much limited to the iframe to begin with, with the exception of a referrer pointing to the embedding domain maybe - access to pretty much everything else is hindered by the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: I have to authorize the sites on my network for same origin with the main server to server the pixels up centrally at all.  Issue is that given that's allowed, I was hoping initially (silly me) iframes would limit the scope.  Upon further reading native behavior is that when you iframe a page, and use client side scripting to determine the "site url" it will tag the top tier domain vs the bottom.  Also noticed through the FB pixel manager it still had access to the top tier domains meta tags + headers when it posted where the event was fired from.

Comment: Long story short - try it, when you iframe a FB \ google pixel they will track all the data as if it came from the highest level in the iframe chain, vs the page that the pixel is actually on.

Comment: Documentation says, _“PageView standard events record the referrer URL of the page that triggered the function call.”_ - and that is the only way I can see what you’re describing happening in the first place, because from within a different domain iframe, JavaScript should not have any other access to the “outside” document to begin with - unless perhaps you embedded the pixel script in the topdomain.com document as well? Then those two instances probably will be communicating via postMessage.

Comment: If(!) it is purely referrer-based, then maybe specifying a `Referrer-Policy` could prevent the script inside the iframe from learning about with outside document referred to it. (Not sure if that would break additional forms of tracking that might be in place and rely on a referrer though.)

Comment: I can do a fast example to prove it but,if I have page A and iframe page B,  the pixel will report as being fired from page A.  Not just that it will have all of page A's meta tags etc in the report (it's not just the referer).  You're right it's 100% counter intuitive, I thought iframing would limit scope too.  The only way I've gotten it to track to page B is removing all JS and firing it as noscript.  Fired as no script it tracks the origin etc to page B.  Fired with js, It basically operates as if it was hard coded on page A (not just referer, headers etc are all page A)

Comment: _“(not just referer, headers etc are all page A)”_ - doesn’t necessarily mean all that was read via client-side JavaScript though - Facebook might simply gather that data by scraping the referrer URL in the background. JavaScript has access to the referrer pointing to A on a document level, but with the noscript image, the referrer would be your document B to begin with, which would explain why it doesn’t happen then.

Comment: Can you try what happens when you forbid sending a referrer using [`Referrer-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)? (Guess that would have to be done for A here, so that that doesn’t send a referrer to B to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `sendMessage` between the main page and the iframe, have some javascript on the "other side" receive the message with `onmessage` event, then send the tracking pixel request there.

Comment: The issue is that they're not my tracking pixels, it's facebook, google etc etc so I don't know what\how to communicate to them.  Basically I'm trying to get the pixels to link up with their origin campaigns when the purchase \ lead side of stuff is fired, vs linking to the top tier site that I'm feeding the leads to.  If I have 3 feeder sites, on 3 different accounts all 3 track to the same top level domain.  This can be semi-solved passing querystings etc, but I'd prefer them to actually fire from the origin domains

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you'll be able to do that. Its against browser SOP etc. The way I suggest, you could handle the message and insert the facebook/google/etc tracking pixels to fire them there. Other than that, you are going to be out of luck.